# Odds on a Raffle... Potential Scam???

Tags: probability, statistics

At my work, we have different departments trying to raise as much money as possible through a christmas raffle.
Unsurprisingly, the person who was running the raffle won the most items, and won an additional cash prize for selling the most tickets.
My plan this morning was to work out the probability, based on tickets sold and prizes won, but my math / stats isn't as good as it once was!
This was the breakdown on tickets sold and prizes won;
Dept 1 - 200 - 3 prizes, 
Dept 2 - 666 - 1 prize,
Dept 3 - 311 - 0 prizes,
Dept 4 - 310 - 0 prizes,
Dept 5 - 205 - 1 prize,
Dept 6 - 751 - 1 prize,
Dept 7 - 346 - 1 prize,
Dept 8 - 766 - 4 prizes (raffle organiser),
Dept 9 - 600 - 1 prize,
Dept 10 - 685 - 0 prizes,
Dept 11 - 146 - 0 prizes,
Dept 12 - 135 - 0 prizes,
Dept 13 - 111 - 1 prize,
Dept 14 - 290 - 0 prizes,
Dept 15 - 95 - 0 prizes,
Dept 16 - 70 - 0 prizes,
Dept 17 - 114 - 2 prizes,

Total tickets - 5801, 15 prizes.

Basically, what is the chance of Dept 8, winning more than a quarter of the prizes, while only selling just over 10% of tickets...?

Thanks folks.

Comment: I think you should do something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test

Comment: Frankly, I'd be more concerned about Department $1$.  They are down at the bottom for number of tickets, yet grossly outperform in prizes,

Comment: Yes Dept 1 vastly over perfromed too... might have to investigate for any signs of colluding

Comment: I don't see anything too weird for department $8$.  We've sold $5801$ tickets representing $15$ prizes.  That means each ticket has a probability $p=0.002585761$ of winning.  With $766$ tickets, $\#8$ expected to win $766p=1.980692984$ with a standard deviation of about $\sigma_8=1.405550207$ which makes $4$ wins on the high side, but hardly miraculous.  Department $\#1$ on the other hand expected to win $0.007757283$ with $\sigma_1=0.718202606$ so they are a $4\sigma$ event.

Comment: My point is that, with small samples, weird things happen.  a couple prizes turns an ordinary patch of good luck into a $4\sigma$ event.  You'll need more than this to convince me that anything untoward is happening.

Comment: Note:  Typo in my numerical comment.  Department $1$ has a mean of $200p=0.517152215$, not what I wrote.